# jQueryui autocomplete with JSON list

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, rest, autocomplete

I'm a noob to jQuery and I need some help with an autocomplete search.

I'm calling a REST service that returns the following:

```
    {
       "success":"true",
       "errmsg":"",
       "list":[
          {
             "ItemDesc":"18 16GA CMP GALV CORR PI",
             "ItemNumber":"78398",
             "ProdNumber":"1318CMP16",
             "Alias":"70370"
          },
          {
             "ItemDesc":"18 16GA CMP GALV BAND",
             "ItemNumber":"83063",
             "ProdNumber":"1318CMP16BG",
             "Alias":"18ACCMPB"
          },
          {
             "ItemDesc":"48 CMP BAND 12G",
             "ItemNumber":"120404",
             "ProdNumber":"1348CMPB",
             "Alias":"CMB1248"
          }
       ]
    }
```

I'm trying to get autocomplete to search those results & display the "ItemDesc" in a list so the user can click one.

```
      $(function () {
          $("#search").autocomplete({
              //source: "/ItemSearch/994/092468/CMP"
          });
      });
```

Currently the only thing that will show in the autocomplete list is "true" (the value of "success" in the JSON result from the REST call).  How can get it to display the list of "ItemDesc"s that were returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in your autocomplete you are using `jQuery.ajax` to make your request to the service. If so, then set the ajax `dataType:` setting to `json`, set up a function in the `success:` setting, then in that function use `.map` to process the returned data into the form you want. You can find a good example of this [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) in the jQuery docs. Following is a relevant snippet from the source of the example on that page:

```
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
            value: item.name
          }
        }));
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm actually using $.getJSON to call the REST service.  Will $.map still work for me or should I back-up & rewrite the REST call with $.ajax?

Comment: `$.getJSON` is just a wrapper around `$.ajax` that sets `dataType: "json"` for you, among a few other things. It takes a success function argument that you could use to define a function that `$.each`s through each item of returned data to get what you want and push it into an array for use in your `$.autocomplete`'s source option. The `$.getJSON` doc has an  example of a success function to get you started. I'd try this route and only back up if you hit a wall or need the full control that `$.ajax` gives you.